# Sequel - ordering a dataset for one-to-many and many-to-many model associations

Tags: mysql, ruby, sequel

I have a question regarding ordering datasets with sequel.

I have tables **'jobs'**, **'users'**, **'comments'**. Users can apply for any job, so I have a many-to-many association here (I also have a 'jobs_users' table). Jobs and comments represent one-to-many association. What I'm trying to implement is the following - I'd like to retrieve rows form **'jobs'**, ordered by:

1. Number of users applied;
2. Number of comments (most commented first).

I use sequel and so far I'm playing with explicit queries, so could you help me to implement such ordering in native sequel way?

Simplified db looks like this:

```
create_table :users do
    primary_key     :id
    String          :nickname
end

create_table :jobs do
    primary_key     :id
    Text            :description
end

create_table :jobs_users do
    primary_key     :id
    foreign_key     :job_id
    foreign_key     :user_id
end

create_table :comments do
    primary_key     :id
    Text            :comment
    foreign_key     :user_id
    foreign_key     :job_id
end
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try this -

```
SELECT j.id,
       COUNT(ju.id) AS appliedcount,
       COUNT(c.id) AS commentcount
FROM jobs j
     JOIN jobs_user ju ON ju.job_id = j.id
     JOIN comments c ON c.job_id = j.id
GROUP BY j.id
ORDER BY appliedcount DESC, commentcount DESC;
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming users can only apply once (perhaps restrict this by making the `primary_key` on the `jobs_users` table `job_id` and `user_id` you could get the number of applications for a job by simply grouping and counting around the `job_id`

```
DB[:jobs_users].group_and_count(:job_id).order(:count.desc).all
```

Same would be for comments. Most commented on jobs would be:

```
DB[:comments].group_and_count(:job_id).order(:count.desc).all
```

Now neither of these return the full record, but they will give you the top `job_id`s that you're looking for.